# Apache Flink: emit output records periodically even if no input records have arrives for a given window

Tags: apache-flink

I keep only the last event saved in a state, and want to emit that state periodically.

Same issue is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59043453/apache-flink-emit-output-records-in-flink-based-on-keyed-state-even-if-no-input), but the accepted answer only give a hint to use timers. Which did not work for me.

Also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635788/calculate-totals-and-emit-periodically-in-flink), but it was a different issue; the input stream there would have so many events in every window. my main problem is that my input stream don't have events for every and each window, yet I want to produce output for every and each window.

First Failed solution:

```
// pseudo code:
keyedStream.window(1 Minute).reduce() // does not emit when no events arrive
```

Another Failed Solution:

```
//Tried with a process function and a timer,
// but timer could only be created in processElement and fires only once.
// it is not periodic

class MyProcessFunction extends KeyedProcessFunction<Integer, Input, Output>{

    public void processElement(Input event, Context context, Collector<Output> out) throws Exception {

        savedState.update(event) // save last event in a state

        // This creates a timer on every event, which is OK
        // and I can easily change the code so that the timer get created only on first event
        // But there was no way to make the timer periodic, independent of arrival of events
        context.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(someWindow);            
    }

    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext context, Collector<Output> out) throws Exception {
        // this emit exactly once
        out.collect(savedState.value());

        // was hoping for something like 
        // context.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(timestamp + someWindow);

       // but there is no access to timerService() here, so I couldn't make the timer periodic
    } 
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register timers in the `onTimer` method; the `OnTimerContext` does have a `TimerService`. What you were hoping for is how it is normally used.

Perhaps if you provide more details we can sort out why it didn't work for you.

Comment: The code I listed in the question is a simplified version. In the original code I used a reduce followed by process, and somehow got Context confused for OnTimerContext. ( It was getting late :P ) ... Oh, and regarding "What you were hoping for is how it is normally used", this made my day. Thanks.